# PinView not showing for Arabic language

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view, arabic

In my application I am using [PinView](https://github.com/ChaosLeong/PinView) library read the number. Now when the language is English this layout is showing and when I change the language to Arabic This view is not showing. Here is the views of Arabic and English. I added background color to check is the view is there or not, The view is there but the Cells are not displaying. Here is the views,

English
[image]

Arabic
[image]

While tap on the orange color the keyboard is opened.

Here is the xml code I used to display,

```
             <com.chaos.view.PinView
                android:id="@+id/pinCodeView"
                style="@style/PinWidget.PinView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                app:lineColor="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:itemCount="10"
                app:itemSpacing="4dp"
                app:viewType="rectangle" />
```

Comment: This issue basically is due to English being an LTR (left to right) language and Arabic being an RTL (right to left) language. So, handle RTL properly in your code, I hope might work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade to version 1.3.0. In 1.2.0, [PinView](https://github.com/ChaosLeong/PinView) does not support RTL.